# Multiple selections of UIView in index iCarousel

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, icarousel

So I want to highlight a specific `UIView` in iCarousel when I click a button within that view and I want to be able to highlight as many views as I want within the carousel. So I have a button that sets the alpha of a `UIImageview` within the view the problem that I'm running into is although it knows the index of the view I don't know how to call the corresponding index of the `UIImageview` within that view. So I setup the `UIImageview` within a custom nib and I have this code setting up the iCarousel's view it:

UPDATED based on @danh answer

```
//.h
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSMutableSet *selected;
//.m
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
 self.selected = [NSMutableSet set];
}

- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{

    //create new view if no view is available for recycling
    if (view == nil)
    {
        view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ItemView" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
}
 int chkTag = checkImg.tag;
checkImg = (UIImageView *)[checkImg viewWithTag:chkTag];

NSNumber *indexNum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:index];
// here's where the view state gets set
checkImg.alpha = ([self.selected member:indexNum])? 1.0 : 0.0;
  return view;
}
```

Then I have this called when the specific view is being selected:

```
- (void)carouselCurrentItemIndexUpdated:(iCarousel *)carousel1{
    NSInteger indexInt = carousel1.currentItemIndex;
NSNumber *index = [NSNumber numberWithInt:indexInt];
if ([self.selected member:index]) {
    [self.selected removeObject:index];
} else {
    [self.selected addObject:index];
}

// now just reload that item, and let the viewForItemAtIndex
// take care of the selection state
[carousel reloadItemAtIndex:indexInt animated:NO];
}
```

Which works but only allows me to select one item at a time and check it. I want to be able to select/unselect multiple items at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works like a table view.  You need is a model for selected items.  This needs to outlive any given carousel view.  So add a `property NSMutableSet *selectedItems` and initialize it with `self.selected = [NSMutableSet set];`

When the button is pressed, you want to add the current index to that set (does that button toggle selection? if so, then you want to add it if it's absent, or remove it if it's present).

```
NSInteger indexInt = carousel1.currentItemIndex;
NSNumber *index = [NSNumber numberWithInt:indexInt];
if ([self.selected member:index]) {
    [self.selected removeObject:iIndex];
} else {
    [self.selected addObject:index];
}

// now just reload that item, and let the viewForItemAtIndex
// take care of the selection state
[carousel reloadItemAtIndex:indexInt animated:NO];
```

The last step is to react to the selection state when you configure a view:

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view {

    if (view == nil) {
        view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ItemView" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
    }

    // get the checkImg view however you do that already.  if you're confused about this
    // give it a tag when you create it, then find it like this:
    UIImageView *checkImg = (UIImageView *)[view viewWithTag:SOME_TAG];

    NSNumber *indexNum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:index];
    // here's where the view state gets set
    checking.alpha = ([self.selected member:indexNum])? 1.0 : 0.0;

  return view;
}
```

EDIT - Part of the problem seems to be creating and then later getting subviews of the carousel. UIView provides a tag property that will help, but the posted code makes a couple errors.  Here's how to use tags:

If you create the image view in IB, give it a tag using the properties inspector.  Here, I gave a view a tag of 32.

[image]

Now SOME_TAG in my suggestion above should be 32, so...

```
UIImageView *checkImg = (UIImageView *)[view viewWithTag:32];
NSLog(@"%@", checkImg);

// if this doesn't log an image view, then something is wrong.
```

Comment: So I added what you said but when I added this
    `int chkTag = checkImg.tag;
    checkImg = (UIImageView *)[view viewWithTag:chkTag];
    NSNumber *indexNum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:index];
    // here's where the view state gets set
    checkImg.alpha = ([self.selected member:indexNum])? 1.0 : 0.0;` but it seems to break the carousel, when I remove `checkImg = (UIImageView *)[view viewWithTag:chkTag];` the carousel seems to work but only the first item checks and unchecks.

Comment: I changed `checkImg = (UIImageView *)[checkImg viewWithTag:chkTag];` to this `checkImg = (UIImageView *)[checkImg viewWithTag:chkTag];` and got it working. But now only one element can be checked at a time when I want multiple items to be checked at a time.

Comment: I updated my question to reflect the changes I made.

Comment: your code additions aren't quite right. you don't get the tag from the image view, you get the image view using the tag.  Set it up in IB with a tag, then search the view for it using that tag.  Please see my edit.

Comment: It logs a UIView, and this line of code still seems to make the carousel blank `checkImg = (UIImageView *)[view viewWithTag:32];` It doesn't throw any errors, it just doesnt load the carousel.

Comment: It's a problem that it logs a UIView, since we think that it's a UIImageView.  I think what's happening is that you're setting the whole view alpha to 0.0.  It's very important that the tag is non-zero and that the tag is set on an UIImageView *subview* of the view you return to the carousel.

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted me to add the tag to the UIView not the UIImageView. It is now working, thank you for the help!